# Add new columns to all triggers in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have 450 tables in my database, I have introduced a new column to all the tables including its history table.

My problem is there are plenty of triggers in my database. How do I add the new column in my trigger code.

For now, I am adding manually by taking the trigger script one by one. But it is a tedious task to do. Could any one please suggest any efficient way to do this process.

Comment: script out all the triggers into one file and make modifications

Comment: Currently I am doing like this only. But it is difficult for me to add those columns even I can't do find and replace.

Comment: This is one of the reasons triggers are frowned upon - they add complexity (and opacity) to your database. Not much help now, I know...

Answer (score 0):

One of easy alternate way is to add one more trigger to each table.
You can create dynamic script like:

```
SELECT 
'CREATE TRIGGER trg_' + name + '_NewFld
ON ' + name + '
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    --WRITER YOUR LOGIC FOR NEWLY ADDED FIELD
END'
from sys.tables
```

Comment: This assumes that the logic for all the tables in the same

Comment: I had a thought of writing like this but unfortunately the logic differs a lot. Same logic applicable only for few triggers.